# wp7.1 & 8 - WebBrowser - NavigateToString - LoadImage

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

We have couple of custom html pages generated at runtime and use NavigateToString to load those html on webbrowser.

We have lot of contents which is generated at runtime and displayed correct, but problem is loading image which is stored in images folder within application.

Search Stackoverflow lot of recommendations of using IsolatedStore and Navigate but our html is generated at runtime. Is it possible to load Image using NavigateTostring?

e.g. code snipte

strHtml = strHtml & " "

### -------

---

```
                "<img style=\'text-align: center;\' src=\""file:///XYZ.jpg\"">" & _

Private Sub WebBrowser_OnLoaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    webBrowser1.NavigateToString(strHtml)
End Sub
```

Doesn't show XYZ.jpg.

Do we really need to save html everytime on isolatedstorage device along with image and then let webbrowser load it? This doesn't make sense.

Please let me know if you there are ways to implement this with NavigateToString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the html pages generated at run-time, that time you have to pass the correct image path to in side the html sting, as per your code whatever path you are putting that would not work while html rendering.

1) You Have to copy all images to IsolatedStorage.

Important to do this select all images from solution explorer and press F4 Key and set the **Build Action** – Content, and **Copy to Output Directory** – Copy always.

See the below code snippet for the same: you can copy once these image to IsolatedStorage.

```
private void CopyToIsolatedStorage(string file, IsolatedStorageFile store, bool overwrite = true)
{
            if (store.FileExists(file) && !overwrite)
                return;

            using (var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
            using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                int bytesRead;
                var buffer = new byte[resourceStream.Length];
                while ((bytesRead = resourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed image property to Copy to Output Direcotry always. Do i still need to use above method. Also i tried replacing src=""XYZ.jpg"" still it shows as not found in rendered image

Comment: yes you have to copy all images explicitly to ISO and have to pass correct path to html. use the CopyToIsolatedStorage() method to copy all image to ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I solved it.. below steps taken

1. Saved Image to IsoStorage
2. Created HTML using String and store HTML to IsoStorage
3. Load stored HTML using WebBrowser.Navigate ( URI ).

Not sure why I simply cannot acccess image using NavigatetoString!